# How to make flashing labels depending on the player?

Tags: python, tkinter

A while ago I had posted a question here about my Connect 4 code, some very nice people helped me out with it. Now I'm stumped on an addition I would like to do to the game. Add a flashing label that flashes between bg=green and bg=red or blue depending on which player "captured" those 4 in a row. Here's my code, thank you in advance.

My best guess right now is to have a def named to like flashWinner() and have it run on every button and flash the colours depending on the winner.

```
from Tkinter import *
from functools import partial
import time

top = Tk()

top.title("Juan's Zany Super Crazy Connect Four!")

turn=1

nextS=[35,36,37,38,39,40,41]

def winFound():
    for f in range(0,7):
        buttonList[0+f].config(state=DISABLED)

def checkWin():
    for h in range (0,4):
        if board[35+h].cget('bg')==board[36+h].cget('bg')==board[37+h].cget('bg')==board[38+h].cget('bg')!='grey80':
            for q in range (0,4):
                global turn
                board[35+h].config(bg='green')
                board[36+h].config(bg='green')
                board[37+h].config(bg='green')
                board[38+h].config(bg='green')
                winFound()
        elif board[28+h].cget('bg')==board[29+h].cget('bg')==board[30+h].cget('bg')==board[31+h].cget('bg')!='grey80':
            for q in range (0,4):
                global turn
                board[28+h].config(bg='green')
                board[29+h].config(bg='green')
                board[30+h].config(bg='green')
                board[31+h].config(bg='green')
                winFound()
        elif board[21+h].cget('bg')==board[22+h].cget('bg')==board[23+h].cget('bg')==board[24+h].cget('bg')!='grey80':
            for q in range (0,4):
                global turn
                board[21+h].config(bg='green')
                board[22+h].config(bg='green')
                board[23+h].config(bg='green')
                board[24+h].config(bg='green')
                winFound()
        elif board[14+h].cget('bg')==board[15+h].cget('bg')==board[16+h].cget('bg')==board[17+h].cget('bg')!='grey80':
            for q in range (0,4):
                global turn
                board[14+h].config(bg='green')
                board[15+h].config(bg='green')
                board[16+h].config(bg='green')
                board[17+h].config(bg='green')
                winFound()
        elif board[7+h].cget('bg')==board[8+h].cget('bg')==board[9+h].cget('bg')==board[10+h].cget('bg')!='grey80':
            for q in range (0,4):
                global turn
                board[7+h].config(bg='green')
                board[8+h].config(bg='green')
                board[9+h].config(bg='green')
                board[10+h].config(bg='green')
                winFound()
        elif board[0+h].cget('bg')==board[1+h].cget('bg')==board[2+h].cget('bg')==board[3+h].cget('bg')!='grey80':
            for q in range (0,4):
                global turn
                board[0+h].config(bg='green')
                board[1+h].config(bg='green')
                board[2+h].config(bg='green')
                board[3+h].config(bg='green')
                winFound()
    for j in range(0,7):
        if board[0+j].cget('bg')==board[7+j].cget('bg')==board[14+j].cget('bg')==board[21+j].cget('bg')!='grey80':
            for q in range (0,4):
                global turn
                board[0+j].config(bg='green')
                board[7+j].config(bg='green')
                board[14+j].config(bg='green')
                board[21+j].config(bg='green')
                winFound()
        elif board[7+j].cget('bg')==board[14+j].cget('bg')==board[21+j].cget('bg')==board[28+j].cget('bg')!='grey80':
            for q in range (0,4):
                global turn
                board[7+j].config(bg='green')
                board[14+j].config(bg='green')
                board[21+j].config(bg='green')
                board[28+j].config(bg='green')
                winFound()
        elif board[14+j].cget('bg')==board[21+j].cget('bg')==board[28+j].cget('bg')==board[35+j].cget('bg')!='grey80':
            for q in range (0,4):
                global turn
                board[14+j].config(bg='green')
                board[21+j].config(bg='green')
                board[28+j].config(bg='green')
                board[35+j].config(bg='green')
                winFound()
    for x in range(0,3):
        if board[35-(7*x)].cget('bg')==board[29-(7*x)].cget('bg')==board[23-(7*x)].cget('bg')==board[17-(7*x)].cget('bg')!='grey80':
            for q in range (0,4):
                global turn
                board[35-(7*x)].config(bg='green')
                board[29-(7*x)].config(bg='green')
                board[23-(7*x)].config(bg='green')
                board[17-(7*x)].config(bg='green')
                winFound()
        elif board[36-(7*x)].cget('bg')==board[30-(7*x)].cget('bg')==board[24-(7*x)].cget('bg')==board[18-(7*x)].cget('bg')!='grey80':
            for q in range (0,4):
                global turn
                board[36-(7*x)].config(bg='green')
                board[30-(7*x)].config(bg='green')
                board[24-(7*x)].config(bg='green')
                board[18-(7*x)].config(bg='green')
                winFound()
        elif board[37-(7*x)].cget('bg')==board[31-(7*x)].cget('bg')==board[25-(7*x)].cget('bg')==board[19-(7*x)].cget('bg')!='grey80':
            for q in range (0,4):
                global turn
                board[37-(7*x)].config(bg='green')
                board[31-(7*x)].config(bg='green')
                board[25-(7*x)].config(bg='green')
                board[19-(7*x)].config(bg='green')
        elif board[38-(7*x)].cget('bg')==board[32-(7*x)].cget('bg')==board[26-(7*x)].cget('bg')==board[20-(7*x)].cget('bg')!='grey80':
            for q in range (0,4):
                global turn
                board[38-(7*x)].config(bg='green')
                board[32-(7*x)].config(bg='green')
                board[26-(7*x)].config(bg='green')
                board[20-(7*x)].config(bg='green')
                winFound()
    for x in range(0,3):
        if board[41-(7*x)].cget('bg')==board[33-(7*x)].cget('bg')==board[25-(7*x)].cget('bg')==board[17-(7*x)].cget('bg')!='grey80':
            for q in range (0,4):
                global turn
                board[41-(7*x)].config(bg='green')
                board[33-(7*x)].config(bg='green')
                board[25-(7*x)].config(bg='green')
                board[17-(7*x)].config(bg='green')
                winFound()
        elif board[40-(7*x)].cget('bg')==board[32-(7*x)].cget('bg')==board[24-(7*x)].cget('bg')==board[16-(7*x)].cget('bg')!='grey80':
            for q in range (0,4):
                global turn
                board[40-(7*x)].config(bg='green')
                board[32-(7*x)].config(bg='green')
                board[24-(7*x)].config(bg='green')
                board[16-(7*x)].config(bg='green')
                winFound()
        elif board[39-(7*x)].cget('bg')==board[31-(7*x)].cget('bg')==board[23-(7*x)].cget('bg')==board[15-(7*x)].cget('bg')!='grey80':
            for q in range (0,4):
                global turn
                board[39-(7*x)].config(bg='green')
                board[31-(7*x)].config(bg='green')
                board[23-(7*x)].config(bg='green')
                board[15-(7*x)].config(bg='green')
                winFound()
        elif board[38-(7*x)].cget('bg')==board[30-(7*x)].cget('bg')==board[22-(7*x)].cget('bg')==board[14-(7*x)].cget('bg')!='grey80':
            for q in range (0,4):
                global turn
                board[38-(7*x)].config(bg='green')
                board[30-(7*x)].config(bg='green')
                board[22-(7*x)].config(bg='green')
                board[14-(7*x)].config(bg='green')
                winFound()  

def buttonStuff(z):
    global turn
    if turn==1:
        board[nextS[z]].config(bg='blue')
        nextS[z]=nextS[z]-7
        turn=turn+1
        if nextS[z]<0:
            buttonList[z].config(state=DISABLED)

    elif turn==2:
        board[nextS[z]].config(bg='red')
        nextS[z]=nextS[z]-7
        turn=turn-1
        if nextS[z]<0:
            buttonList[z].config(state=DISABLED)

    checkWin()

top = Tk()
r=0
count=0
col=0

buttonList = list()
for z in range(7):
    buttonList.append(Button(text=str(z), font='times 48', command=partial(buttonStuff, z)))
    buttonList[-1].grid(row=r,column=col, sticky='NESW')
    count+=1
    col+=1

r=1
col=0
count=0

board = list()
for z in range(42):
        board.append(Label(text='', font='Helvetica 15', bg='grey80'))
        board[-1].grid(row=r,column=col, sticky='NESW', padx=2, pady=2, ipadx=2, ipady=25)
        count+=1
        col+=1
        if count==7:
            r=r+1
            count=0
            col=0


top.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can't you replace most of those repeated conditions with a condition in a loop? Also, in all those `for q in range (0,4):` loops, you are never using `q`, and neither `turn`.

Comment: Also, from a design point of view it might be better to store the state of the game in a list of lists instead of in the buttons themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too big for a comment so.

Here's one route you could go. Create a label using `label = tk.Label(root,....)` and put it wherever you want top, bottom of the root window wherever. Call `grid_forget()` on the widget to hide it initially, create the function you were thinking of then call `grid()` to replace it on the grid. I don't see a way you're keeping track of the players glossing over your code. It's a bit hard to read at points. So you could create a tuple like `players = ('Player 1', 'Player 2')` and then on each turn switch the index to point to the current player. You could then have a reference to what current player's turn it was and hence who just won the game. You could then make a loop caling `label.config(..)` inside of it to switch the color based upon a condition (which player won) to make the colors "flash".

Addendum: You could cut that code down to ~1/10th of it's current size.

Comment: Since he is already using `grid()`, it probably isn't best practice to use any `pack` functions.

Comment: Right you are, I didn't notice `grid` at first thanks for pointing out. I really just skimmed over the code was a bit hard to follow.

Comment: I actually cut down the size of the code with a Nested Loop by a lot. It's just now working on getting the flashing working :/. I'll try your method and see how it works, thank you.